# Bulk Upload of files using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, activerecord, paperclip, rake-task

I need to bulk upload around 225 pdf files.  Im using paperclip to do this.

I can write a rake task to do this but the file name is what is tripping me up.  I cannot figure out how to give each file that is being uploaded its own individual name from the rake task.

Ex:

file = S100020_C.pdf
the file_name would have to be in this format though = 100020

Maybe use a regex?

Comment: \d+ should dp it in your case

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, why not use a count? Eg:

```
files.each_with_index do |file, i|
  filename = "1000#{i}_C.pdf"
end
```

You could append the count to the existing file names so that each file has a unique 'id'